# printing next several lines after if statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new at python, im trying to write a code to print several lines after an if statement.

for example, I have a file "test.txt" with this style:

```
Hello
how are you?
fine thanks
how old are you?
24
good
how old are you?
i am 26
ok bye.
Hello
how are you?
fine
how old are you?
13
good
how old are you?
i am 34
ok bye.
Hello
how are you?
good
how old are you?
17
good
how old are you?
i am 19
ok bye.
Hello
how are you?
perfect
how old are you?
26
good
how old are you?
i am 21
ok bye.
```

so I want to print one line after each "how old are you"
my code is like this:

```
fhandle=open('test.txt')
for line in fhandle:
   if line.startswith('how old are you?')
      print(line) /*** THIS IS THE PROBLEM
```

I want to print next line after how old are you ( maybe print two lines after "how old are you" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readlines()` function that returnes lines of a file as a list and use `enumerate()` function to loop through list elements:

```
lines = open('test.txt').readlines()

for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('how old are you?'):
        print(lines[i+1], line[i+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the file to a list and use a variable which increases by 1 for each line:

```py
fhandle = list(open('test.txt'))
i = 1
for line in fhandle:
    if line.startswith('how old are you?')
        print(fhandle[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always two more lines after each "how old are you", you could just skip to the next iteration by using `next(fhandle)` like this:

```
fhandle = open('test.txt')
for line in fhandle:
    if line.startswith('how old are you?'):
        print(line)
        print(next(fhandle))
        print(next(fhandle))
```

Remember that the for loop just uses `fhandle` as an iterator! :)

Answer (score 0):

So as you want to print next line (or two lines) I suggest to use list index. to do that use `readlines()` to convert the file to a `list`:

```py
fhandle = open('test.txt').readlines()
```

After you did this you can use `len` to calculate list length and index it in a for loop and print next two lines.

```py
for line_index in range(len(fhandle)):
    if fhandle[line_index].startswith('how old are you?'):
        print(fhandle[line_index + 1], fhandle[line_index + 2])
```